# background image not changing for button onclick

Tags: android, image, button, onclick, drawable

On button click I want to change the background image of the button but its not working for me.

What is the exact problem?

Help is always appreciated.

```
      private Button seatdirnbtn;
      seatdirnbtn.setOnClickListener(seathtlistner);
 private View.OnClickListener seathtlistner = new View.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.drawable.icon4:
        seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4hlt);
        break;
    case R.drawable.icon4hlt:
        seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4);

    }
}
```

Comment: on which view are you setting this listener?

Comment: How you are setting click event for drawable's `R.drawable.icon4hlt` or  `R.drawable.icon4` ?

Comment: i think you want to change Button background on the basis of Current background drawable then your current logic if not right. you will need to get current background drawable id on button click and change it

Comment: yes thanks a lot let me try

Comment: we have a method `getDrawable(seatdirnbtn) ` try it to get current background drawable id

Comment: @ imran khan, No  I am not getting getDrawable(seatdirnbtn) method for the button

Comment: how can we get the current background drawable?

Comment: @Raghav : you can use your on logic using booelan variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try as to change Button background when user click in Button:

```
 private Button seatdirnbtn;
 public static boolean isclick=false;
 seatdirnbtn.setOnClickListener(seathtlistner);
 private View.OnClickListener seathtlistner = new View.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if(isclick){
      seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4hlt);
    }else{
      seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4);
    }
    isclick=!isclick;
}
```